# Disable angularJS routing for a specific url

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a static sitemap.xml file which sits in the root of my server and needs to be served as is. Unfortunately, when I use the url www.mydomain.com/sitemap.xml it is rewritten by angularJS routing engine to http://www.mydomain.com/sitemap.xml#!/

Is there any way to disable angularJS routing only for a specific url? I can't modify webserver configuration so it must be done from angularJS conf.

Thanks

Comment: did u try target="_self" in anchor tag this could work but i am not sure

Comment: there is no anchor tag unfortunately. sitemap.xml it's used by automatic bots to index website, therefore it must work as straight url in the browser

Comment: The only way that angular bootstraps is if you serve up the index file when a request is made. In other words, when you request `/sitemap.xml`, your index is served instead. This is probably purely a server issue seeing as no matter how you request that route, you're going to get your angular app instead.