# Where to put sitemap.xml in HTML5 mode angular application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, seo, sitemap, googlebot

My angular appication with HTML5 mode is hosted in a node js server.I am using phantom js to generate snapshots and provide that snapshots to search bots.But I am not sure about where should I add sitemap.xml file in my application.If I put in public folder or some other folder It cannot be taken by bots because of angular routing.Please suggest a way to add sitemap.xml in my site

Answer (score 0):

You can sitemap.xml to any folder on your site. Moreover you can use sitemap.xml on other domain if you specify this robots.txt.

In your case you need to disable Angular Js routing for specific URL. Read [Disable angularJS routing for a specific url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912719/disable-angularjs-routing-for-a-specific-url) and other related questions.